# Existing Angular 2 App and Cordova

Tags: cordova, angular

I have done some searching and can't seem to find an answer to my question.

I have an existing Angular 2 application. Can I use Cordova to build it for multiple platforms? If not are there special steps to take to make this happen? Is there any actual documentation on how this works?

Before it is suggested I'll make it known I want nothing to do with Ionic.

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can add cordova support to your existing Angular2 app. I haven't found any official documentation but there are several resources that give some useful hints on how to.

See [here](https://www.becompany.ch/en/blog/2016/10/19/creating-apache-cordova-app-with-angular2),  [here](https://medium.com/@nacojohn/convert-your-angular-project-to-mobile-app-using-cordova-f0384a7711a6) and [here](http://www.codemag.com/article/1701031/Cordova-Apps-with-Angular-and-TypeScript)

Basic steps will be:

- Create a cordova project: cordova create myApp com.example MyApp
- Add necessary platforms:  cordova platform add myPlatform
- Copy all the created files from your new cordova project into your existing angular project except from: **www folder** and **package.json** file
- Merge your angular package.json with the contents of the new cordova ackage.json.
- Change your existing angular build script to output the dist files into the www folder so cordova can find the final source files.

By here you should be able to run **cordova run android/ios/browser** and your app should work. If you need to use cordova specific plugins you will need to add this to your **index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Don't worry the cordova build will make sure this file exists on the target platform.

Then on your **main.ts** or **index.ts** add a check to see if the device is ready and bootstrap your angular app. Something like this:

```
let bootstrap = () => {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}

if(window['cordova']){
    console.log("Cordova found")
    document.addEventListener('deviceready',bootstrap);
} else {
    console.log("Cordova not found")
    bootstrap()
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks! just one thing, there are things in node_modules in the cordova app that need to be copied to the angular app, some how, merging the tow folders didn't work for me, I don't know what those things are, but if you don't want to mess around replacing and skipping files, I'd backup and remove the angular node_modules directory, copy the cordova one, then run npm install in the angular app to restore all the project's libraries.