# Build mobile App - Angular 2 + Cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, mobile

I have cloned the following GitHub project (Quickstart with Angular):

- https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git quickstart

in order to create a Mobile Application(iOS and Android) using Cordova.

How can I convert the Angular 2 project to a Cordova application?

As far as I am aware I do not use neither Angular CLI nor Gulp.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily for converting, but have you considered Ionic? It was built for making cross platform apps built on the angular platform.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/

I've built a few apps with this (nothing huge) and it works well.

They  also have a "Drag 'n Drop" solution called "Ionic Creator" if you'd like to template before you code.

Comment: Do I need to change the AngularJS project if I use Ionic?

Comment: If you have an existing project, Ionic may not be the choice for you. You would have to migrate over to it. You may end up with a web code-base and a mobile code-base (although Ionic now supports "desktop" apps as of v3). If you are starting a new project, I would run through Ionic's getting started / tutorial. Additionally, are you using Angular (v2+) or AngularJS (v1.x)? Note that they are not compatible.

Comment: I am using Angular v2 and I would like to use Cordova so I do not have to start a project from scratch. Ionic could be a good idea for my next :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same recently and it was easier as I expected.

In short you can simple create an empty cordova project using cordova CLI and merge all the files with your existing angular project except for the **package.json** which you will need to merge manually.

See further instructions on my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49443826/3792636)

Hope it helps.